# Can Application.terminate lead to memory leak?

Tags: delphi, memory-leaks, delphi-xe2

At one point of time, I have to terminate my application developed in Delphi XE2 using Application.Terminate.

I would like to confirm, will there be any memory loss due to this? 
If yes, what all possible scenarios I need to take care of? 
And how to tackle them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Calling the [`Application.Terminate`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Forms.TApplication.Terminate) method doesn't produce memory leaks this method is equivalent to call the [PostQuitMessage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644945%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function. The memory leaks are caused when the resources are not released properly. To check if you have memory leaks in your app you can set the global variable [`ReportMemoryLeaksOnShutdown`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Configuring_the_Memory_Manager) to true.

Answer (score 5):

No matter how you close a process, no memory will be leaked. When a process closes, the OS reclaims all the memory owned by the process.

Now, [`Application.Terminate`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Forms.TApplication.Terminate) results in an orderly shutdown, starting at the `Application` object. All objects owned by `Application` will be destroyed. If those objects in turn own other objects, the owned objects will be destroyed. However, in terms of leaking memory it is not possible for a process to terminate and leak memory. It is possible for a process to terminate and leave certain resources in an ill-defined state which is why it is often advisable to terminate a process in an orderly fashion.

Comment: 1. How to terminate a process in an orderly fashion? 2. How this Application.terminate behaves in case of open database connection? Will it take care this as well? Will it cause any issue?

Comment: `Application.Terminate` does an orderly shutdown. The database connection will be closed if your code closes it during shutdown.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. What if there are many query components with open connection, and my code is not handling that before terminating? will that create any problem?